# Dynamic number of tabs using ionic2-super-tabs tag

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I do not have fixed number of tabs in my app page, so that using *ngFor in ionic2-super-tabs tag to get dynamic tabs as mentioned in below ts and html.

typescript :

```
import { AustraliaPage } from './australia';
import {CanadaPage} from './canada';

export class CountryPage {

Australia = AustraliaPage; 
Canada= CanadaPage;
tabsLoaded = false;

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.testservice.getCoutrynames().subscribe(countries => {
        this.tabs = countries;
          // below is the output data of getCoutrynames() method
          //      "countries": [
          //           {
          //           "country_id": 1,
          //           "countryName": "Canada"
          //           },
          //           {
          //           "country_id": 2,
          //           "countryName": "Australia"
          //           }
          //   ]
        this.tabsLoaded = true;
      })
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
 <super-tabs scrollTabs="true" *ngIf="tabsLoaded">
            <super-tab  *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [root]="tab.countryName"  title="tab.countryName"></super-tab>
 </super-tabs>
```

But getting a below error.

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: Australia
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I have the full code I cant seem to get the tabs working

Comment: @SbonisoMarcusNzimande I made the changes in my above code as mentioned in the answer like I added map variable 
pages = {
    Australia: AustraliaPage,
    Canada: CanadaPage
};   **and used this HTML**                                                                                        <super-tabs scrollTabs="true" *ngIf="tabsLoaded">
            <super-tab  *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [root]="pages[tab.countryName]"  [title]="tab.countryName"></super-tab>
 </super-tabs>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the root to the string `'Australia'` not the `Australia` object/page. Do something like this:

```
pages = {
    Australia: AustraliaPage,
    Canada: CanadaPage,
    ...
};

<super-tabs scrollTabs="true" *ngIf="tabsLoaded">
            <super-tab  *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [root]="pages[tab.countryName]"  title="tab.countryName"></super-tab>
 </super-tabs>
```